# C# Concurrent and Async Socket Connections

Tags: c#, multithreading, sockets, asynchronous

I'm working on a simple socket server that is supposed to take in multiple connections and hand them off to a "connection" class by means of `EndAccept()` The problem is that after accepting a connection, the code doesn't accept anything further until the connection ends.

I create the socket in `Main()` like so, then I pass the socket to ServerEnvironment (static class) via `Initialize()`.

```
MainSocket.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(Addr), Port));
MainSocket.Listen(10);

ServerEnvironment.Initialize(MainSocket);

while (true)
{
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine(">>");
}
```

Once `MainSocket` has been passed, ServerEnvironment takes over from there.

```
static Socket MainSocket;

public static void Initialize(Socket _MainSocket)
{
    MainSocket = _MainSocket;

    AcceptGameConnection = new AsyncCallback(AddConnection);
    MainSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptGameConnection, null);
}

public static void AddConnection(IAsyncResult Result)
{
    Socket UserSocket = MainSocket.EndAccept(Result);
    ConnectionCount++;

    // Removed the stuff that happens to UserSocket because the same
    // symptoms occur regardless of their presence.

    MainSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptGameConnection, null);
 }
```

As I search about this question, I come to find that multithreading could be a necessity for my purposes. However, when I use `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` in both `Initialize();` and `AddConnection();`, two different thread IDs appear, so I assume that multithreading is already a capability and I don't need to manually create a thread. That wouldn't explain my issue, though.

Is multithreading necessary for me to be able to have concurrent and asynchronous socket connectivity?

EDIT:
Binding error..was binding to my LAN address which caused some problems.

Comment: maybe you should take a look at http://www.asp.net/signalr, wich is a really easy to use library

Comment: Are you using .net >= 4.5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how you want to do this if you are using .net 4.0 or less

```
public static void Initialize(Socket _MainSocket)
{
    MainSocket = _MainSocket;

    AcceptGameConnection = new AsyncCallback(AddConnection);
    MainSocket.BeginAccept(result => {
        var userSocket = MainSocket.EndAccept(result);
        var thread = new Thread(AddConnection);
        thread.Start(userSocket);
        Initialize(MainSocket);
    }, null);
 }

 public static void AddConnection(IAsyncResult Result)
 {
     MainSocket.BeginAccept(AcceptGameConnection, null);
 }

 private static void AddConnection(Socket userSocket)
 {
     // Removed the stuff that happens to UserSocket because the same
     // symptoms occur regardless of their presence.
 }
```

But this is how you can do it in .net 4.5 or above.

```
public static void Initialize(Socket mainSocket)
{           
    while(true)
    {
        var userSocket = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(
                                mainSocket.BeginAccept,
                                mainSocket.EndAccept);
        ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(_ => AddConnection(userSocket));
    }
 }

 private static void AddConnection(Socket userSocket)
 {
     // Removed the stuff that happens to UserSocket because the same
     // symptoms occur regardless of their presence.
 }
```

Comment: So I'll definitely try the above and even the latter, but would you mind explaining to me why my method works for other applications? I looked at some other game socket servers and they used my exact pattern.

Comment: @Fuselight The problem is that you can't open new connections until you call `BeginAccept` again. Because that is what `BeginAccept` does, ACCEPT new connections. What I am doing is starting up a thread to do work and calling `BeginAccept` straight away. Your other applications might work because the "work" you are doing is reasonably fast to complete.

Comment: In effect for a server to open many connections you really need to call `Accept` as soon as a user connects.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that after accepting a connection, the code doesn't accept anything further until the connection ends.

This happens because the next `BeginAccept` call is delayed by something, probably by code not shown here. Accepting asynchronously is almost always pointless. Don't copy blindly from the terrible Microsoft tutorials. Your accept loop should be:

```
while (true) {
 var socket = Accept();
 StartProcessing(socket); //Cannot block!
}
```

That's all.

You can implement `StartProcessing` using `Task` and `await`. This makes asynchronous socket IO rather simple to do. Alternatively, start a new task/thread per connection that you receive.

> simple socket server

Such a thing does not exist. You better leave sockets alone and use a ready made higher level protocol such as WCF or HTTP.

Comment: "This happens because the next BeginAccept call is delayed by something, probably by code not shown here." Actually, no! I removed that code in the program itself and it _still_ hung! It's super weird. "Start a new task/thread per connection that you receive." I don't know much about sockets but I do know this is a bad idea at a certain number of connections. There's a reason I avoided that. And I cant use a different protocol, as this is software with a pre-designed protocol.

Comment: Regarding Accept not continuing, are you sure that a new connection is even coming in? Anyway, you should switch to the simpler accept loop in any case. There is *no* reason to use async accept here. All people who don't know what they are doing and copy from others.; Regarding thread, sure just use async IO with await then. Google ".net socket await".; No matter what you do, drop the APM pattern.

Comment: I'm absolutely sure that the connection isn't being acknowledged. Also, would accept not block the already-existing connections?

Comment: No, those should be run using async IO. They are using independent sockets. Accepted sockets are not tied to their "parent" socket.

Comment: Prove, that there are multiple incoming connections. Write literally: `MainSocket.Accept();MainSocket.Accept();`. Does the second line complete? If not *you are wrong* and there is no 2nd connection.

Comment: Then your original code is likely to just work. I advise you to rewrite it in a modern way as recommended, but it will work.

Comment: Wait, what's the problem here? I'm opening two sockets and only one is connecting. Even when I disconnect one, the second one doesn't get accepted, even when I reload the webpage. This is a flash client, by the way..

Comment: If you fail to accept two connections using that failsafe piece of test code then there are not two connections incoming. Bug in the client.